# retain first value in group

Tags: r

I wish to retain the first value of a variable by group.  The code below does this, but uses `for-loops` and seems overly complex.  Is there a more efficient way, particularly in base `R`?  The object `desired.result` contains my desired result.

```
my.data <- read.table(text = '

     my.string   my.cov  my.id
     11.......      1      1
     1.1......      3      2
     ..1.2....      4      2
     ....2.2..      5      2
     12.......      2      3
     .22......      3      3
     ..24.....      3      3
     1...2....      1      4
     ....2...4      0      4
     ..2..4...      5      5
', header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, na.strings = 'NA')

desired.result <- read.table(text = '

     my.string   my.cov  my.id
     11.......      1      1
     1.1......      3      2
     ..1.2....      3      2
     ....2.2..      3      2
     12.......      2      3
     .22......      2      3
     ..24.....      2      3
     1...2....      1      4
     ....2...4      1      4
     ..2..4...      5      5
', header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, na.strings = 'NA')

my.seq <- rle(my.data$my.id)$lengths
my.data$first <- unlist(lapply(my.seq, function(x) seq(1,x)))
my.data$last  <- unlist(lapply(my.seq, function(x) seq(x,1,-1)))

my.data$my.new.cov <- rep(NA, nrow(my.data))

for(i in 1:nrow(my.data)) {
    if(my.data$first[i] == 1) my.data$my.new.cov[i] = my.data$my.cov[i]
    if(my.data$first[i] >  1) my.data$my.new.cov[i] = my.data$my.new.cov[(i - 1)]
}

my.data$my.cov <- my.data$my.new.cov

my.data <- my.data[, c('my.string', 'my.cov', 'my.id')]

all.equal(my.data, desired.result)

# [1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 3):

This seems to do it:

```
my.data$my.cov <- ave(my.data$my.cov, my.data$my.id, FUN = function(x) head(x,1))
```

Answer (score 3):

We can use `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(my.data)[,  my.cov := my.cov[1L], by = my.id]
my.data
#    my.string my.cov my.id
# 1: 11.......      1     1
# 2: 1.1......      3     2
# 3: ..1.2....      3     2
# 4: ....2.2..      3     2
# 5: 12.......      2     3
# 6: .22......      2     3
# 7: ..24.....      2     3
# 8: 1...2....      1     4
# 9: ....2...4      1     4
#10: ..2..4...      5     5
```

NOTE: The `base R` solution (`split`) posted will give incorrect results in some caes if it is not sorted.

Comment: @PierreLafortune  I loaded dplyr before.  Corrected.

Comment: Ok I thought it was a new one

Comment: @PierreLafortune  The `last` is there is in both dplyr and data.table.  So I thought `first` should be also present.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a base R solution:

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(split(my.data, my.data$my.id), 
        function(group) {
            group$my.cov = group$my.cov[1]; group }))

    my.string my.cov my.id
1   11.......      1     1
2.2 1.1......      3     2
2.3 ..1.2....      3     2
2.4 ....2.2..      3     2
3.5 12.......      2     3
3.6 .22......      2     3
3.7 ..24.....      2     3
4.8 1...2....      1     4
4.9 ....2...4      1     4
5   ..2..4...      5     5
```

Comment: According to akrun, your solution will give incorrect results.  Although it seems to give the correct result in this example.

Comment: I am not sure. It is possible.

Comment: `by` = `lapply` + `split` , which means you can use `do.call(rbind, by(my.data, my.data$my.id....` - I don't think this will give incorrect results as the `split` will work sequentially. The output result may be in a different order to that produced by `ave`, but the correct values should be found. I think `ave` is probably preferable here as it is essentially `split(x,grp) <- lapply(split(x,grp),FUN)` under the hood anyway.